# Flutter Image gets blurred to red and black when screen size changes

Tags: html, flutter, google-chrome, responsive, flutter-web

[image]

Hi everyone, we're having problem when using flutter web.
What happens:

- we run `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer canvaskit` and `flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html` but nothing changes
- we open `inspect` on browser, then close it quickly, suddenly the image is broken like shown in the picture.
- image format is `.png`

Does anyone here know what might cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Just remove the width and height of the image, and adjust the image width and height on image editing tools.**

*from this*

```
               Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png'),
                    height: 130,
                    width: 130),
```

*into this*

```
               Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/logo.png')),
```

**If this not works than try this**

```
Image yourImage;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  yourImage= Image.asset('assets/logo.png');
}
  
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {
  super.didChangeDependencies();
  precacheImage(yourImage.png, context);
}
```

**If both not works than the problem with your image. Just change your image**
***I hope this will help, Thank you.***